# Express not loading image with absolute path

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm making a NodeJS app, and I've got a div element with a background-image being set in an external CSS file. The CSS file itself works absolutely fine, no problems there. Also, when I load the HTML without Node, the background image shows up just fine.

CSS:

```
#schoolInfo {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('slide1pic.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(serv);
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('client/home'));

app.post('/createSchool', function(req, res) {

  app.use(express.static('client/school'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/school/index.html'));

  io.emit('updateSchool', response);
});

serv.listen(3000);
console.log("Server started on localhost://3000");
```

As is evident, I'm using an absolute URL, so I don't know why express can't find it. I'm getting no errors in Command Prompt (which is where I'm running the server from) or the browser's console.

Do I need to add something to my app.js? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You get no errors in the browser?  Can you look at the sources tab and find your css file?

Comment: @IrkenInvader Yep, it's right there.

Comment: Could you try putting the image in the same folder as your html and referencing it without the path?

Comment: @IrkenInvader Tried that, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your routing form the url where you are serving your files:

```
app.use('/', express.static('client/home'));
```

The **path** '/' is relative from where you start your node process.

If you have an index.html file inside of your **home** directory than you can have an **images** folder there and your express.static() would look like this:

```
app.use('/images', express.static('client/home'));
```

And in your **html** file all you need is to put:

```
<img src="images/file.png" />
```

Then you just need to start you node process at:

```
client\home > node server.js
```

Comment: How would this work if my images are in `client/assets/images`?

Comment: You could do like this: app.use('/images', express.static('client/assets'));

Comment: This will map /images to client/assets/images:                             
app.use('/images', express.static('client/assets/images'));

Comment: If I just put `<img src="images/file.jpg"/>` in my index.html file, the image shows up fine. But if I use `background-image` in my external CSS file, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Where are you placing your css files? Are you defining a class to load this image in the background? Can you show your css?

Comment: The CSS files are in the same folder as the HTML. I'll update the question.

Comment: If you have all inside school, an images folder, the index.html file and the css file, you can have your middleware like this: app.use('/images', express.static('/client/school/images')) and your css like: background-image: url('images/slide1pic.jpg');

Comment: So if I just replace `app.use('/images', express.static('/client/school/images')) ` with `app.use('/images', express.static('client/assets/images'))` then that would also work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189908/discussion-between-william-jones-and-carlos-jafet-neto).

Comment: how to use this with cloud functions